# I try to use ox.graph_ from_ Place to obtain the road network data, but the connection failed

Tags: osmnx

[image: when I try to use ox.graph_from_place][image: it gives]
I try to use ox.graph_ from_ place to obtain the road network data, but the connection fails

Comment: Have you checked your connection and tried again?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have always been connected and tried many times.In fact, in osmnx .graph module, only the function ox.graph_ from_ place failed. A similar problem has occurred in other modules.